# Problems Testing Sling Model with Custom Injectors

Tags: junit, aem, sling, sling-models

I've been doing some work with sling models for a project and in the process created a couple of custom injectors. Everything seems to work great when implemented (used in AEM). However, when I'm testing the custom injectors are not getting run.

Here's an example of what I currently have set up

**In MyModel**

```java
@Inheritable
@CustomAnnotation("foo")
private String _foo
```

**In test** (tests using wcm.io mocking Libraries)

```java
@Rule
AemContext context = new AemContext(ResourceResolverType.RESOURCERESOLVER_MOCK);

//required by the injector
@Mock
InheritanceService _inheritanceService;

@Mock
InheritableInjector _inheritanceInjector;

@Before
public void setup() {
    context.registerService(InheritanceService.class, _inheritanceService);
    context.registerService(InheritableInjector.class, _inheritanceInjector);

    context.addModelsForPackage("com.package.example.models");

    //use this resource in tests to adaptTo(MyModel.class)
    _resource = context.load().json("myJson.json", "/myPath");
}

... tests
```

The tests compile and run, but the Injector isn't being executed. I know it's registered because when I don't have the Injector's dependent services registered in the context I get an error. When I debug through it, none of the breakpoints are hit. I'm wondering if I need to also register the "Inheritable" annotation somewhere or if anyone just has any general information on how I can get the custom injector to execute.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out my error. So the important thing to remember about Sling Model Injectors is that they are just OSGI services (something I completely let myself get away from).

So just treating them like normal services and then remembering to annotate the Injector with `@InjectMocks` was what I needed to do in order to fix the error.

The following now works great.

```
@Mock
InheritanceService _inheritanceService; //injector dependency

@InjectMocks
InheritanceInjector _inheritanceInjector;

@Before
public void setup() {
    context.registerService(InheritanceService.class, _inheritanceService);
    context.registerService(InheritableInjector.class, _inheritanceInjector);
}
```

hopefully that helps anyone that might run into the issue. If anyone can make this answer better please feel free to reply/edit.

Comment: Hi Brodie, I came across a similar issue you faced with testing custom injectors.
My case is not quite the same as yours since the custom injector wasn't implemented by me, but the @AemObject from ACS AEM Commons.

It would be interesting to know your thoughts about it, perhaps you can help me understand what is wrong with the code shared here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993268/sling-model-unit-tests-mock-currentpage-in-slinghttpservletrequest

Thanks in advance for sharing your findings.